# Can connect to NTFS NAS via Windows 10, but not via MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)

Tags: networking, mac, nas

I am running a FRITZ!Box 6591 Cable as my wireless router in my home. I have connected a 1.5 TB Toshiba external HDD to this router via USB. The drive is formatted as NTFS, but to my knowledge that shouldn't matter here to the Mac, since it is a network drive,

I can access the drive on both of my windows 10 PCs via `\\fritz.box\fritz.nas`

However, on my Macbook running MacOS Catalina (10.15.3), if I open Finder and press **⌘-k**, and then try to connect to the NAS via

`smb://fritz.box/fritz.nas`,

I get a window asking me for my login-credentials, which I enter (same as on the Windows 10 machines), but the login fails, and I am not able to access the drive.

At first I thought this may be due to the NAS requiring SMB1, which does not seem to be supported by Catalina out of the box. So I followed the steps at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362739/what-causes-some-network-drives-using-smb-no-longer-connect-to-macos-catalina/363648#363648, and then restared my Macbook.

However, I am still getting the same issues.

**How can I connect to this NAS via my Mac?**

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try connecting with `cifs://fritz.box/fritz.nas`

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. Unfortunately that doesn't work either, with the same problem occuring.